# ReportViewer IIF expression returns #error

Tags: vb.net, reportviewer

I've spent 2 days to figure this out, but no luck.
I have an IIF expression what shows the correct value when the condition goes true (IPmt calculated), but the else always returns #error, although it should be just 0.

```
=IIf(Fields!PaymentNumber.Value<>0,
     IPmt(Fields!Annual_Interest_Rate.Value/1200,Fields!PaymentNumber.Value,Fields!Payment.Value,Fields!Total_Amount_Financed.Value),
     0)
```

All fields have values (can not be null)
What can cause this ?

thanks

Comment: Solved!

Problem caused by the IIF expression evaluation. vb.net tries to calculate the true and false case also. If PaymentNumber is 0, then IPmt returns #Error (division by zero).

Solution: set PaymentNumber to 1 (or something else except 0) inside IPmt when it equals to 0.

Comment: d'OH just finished writing my response below.  Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because the true condition is always evaluated and returns an error when PaymentNumber = 0.  According to the documentation, both conditions of an IIF expression are always evaluated.  You can test this by switching the order:

```
=IIf(Fields!PaymentNumber.Value=0, 0, 
    IPmt(Fields!Annual_Interest_Rate.Value/1200,Fields!PaymentNumber.Value,Fields!Payment.Value,Fields!Total_Amount_Financed.Value))
```

What I've done in the past is create a function in 'custom code'.  I haven't used IPmt, but I believe this should work:

```
Function CalcIpmt(Annual_Interest_Rate As Decimal, PaymentNumber As Integer, Payment As Decimal, Total_Amount_Financed As Decimal) As Decimal)

    If PaymentNumber = 0 Then
        Return 0
    Else
        Return IPmt(Annual_Interest_Rate, PaymentNumber, Payment, Total_Amount_Financed)
    End If 

End Function
```

Then your expression would be:

```
=Code.CalcIpmt( Fields!Annual_Interest_Rate.Value/1200, Fields!PaymentNumber.Value, Fields!Payment.Value, Fields!Total_Amount_Financed.Value )
```

(NOTE: I haven't tested this, and you'll need to check the data types)